# how to avoid and prevent the duplication between two tables in the laravel migration?

Tags: php, database, laravel-6, laravel-7

[image: Website will be required to design the databse]
I'm developing the CMS(College Management System) website using **LARAVEL PHP framework**. Now we need to build up to three types of consoles(Admin, Student, Employee). I'm stuck in the admin console that admin is able to perform the selections process. I have performed the task for the following.

Foreach series has many Users.
Foreach users have one Profile.
Foreach profile has many qualifications, experiences, attendances..
Students and Employees Record saved in the user's table.

Now we need to remove students and employees written in the eclipse shape because there is a duplication code in these two tables(student and employee), then we need to create the profiles table. 
Now remaining tables classes and courses(I have not yet decided what type of relation).
If you need any code from this example then I will add in the comments section.

Comment: I really have trouble understanding what do you need exactly. What are consoles? Why do you need to remove students and employees? What is preventing you to remove it? Why can't you create a profile table? What is duplicating?

Comment: I really require to do that an admin will select the for every employee can take the class or more classes. also, an admin will select which students can take at least one class from this teacher or not. The console is like Panel System because admin will be under-control for the website. Admin will check that's How a website is working or there is any feedback from client.

Comment: I have a table for employees and students.

Comment: `Schema::create('employees', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->string('full_name');
            $table->string('father_name');
            $table->string('date_of_birth');
            $table->string('religion');
            $table->string('province');
            $table->text('address');
            $table->string('nationality');
        });`

Comment: `Schema::create('students', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->string('full_name');
            $table->string('father_name');
            $table->string('date_of_birth');
            $table->string('religion');
            $table->string('province');
            $table->text('address');
            $table->string('nationality');
        });`

Comment: here I have attached the code because It is the same code for both tables(students and employee). If I want to remove these tables Then I want to create Profiles Table. It will be perfectly remove duplicates code in these tables.

Comment: If want to keep it these tables(students and employees) then no need to create a profiles table. and tell me how to avoid and prevent the duplications for this code (students and employees table). Now finally I have two option:- first option. how to remove duplicates in these tables then no need to create a profile table. second option. if I can't remove duplicates in these tables then I need to create a profile table. and also, tell me what is relation between classes, profiles and courses because I can't find the best relationships. and Which option will be best.

Answer (score 0):

In order to prevent duplication (if `students` and `employees` will always be the same entity) is to introduce a new model in the system called `Person` (or something similar). Then you will create additionally a `PersonType` enabling you to expand the model further if you ever need something more than student and employee.

DB schema would then have a relationship:

```
persons ---- M:1 ---- person_types
```

Where `person_types` would have:

```
ID Name
1  Student
2  Employee
```

This way you can reuse everything.

Comment: your idea is very good.. I have a users table that column name user_role. if user_role is student then student has one profile. students has many courses. if user_role is employee. employee has one profile. employee has many classes. class has many students.. and so on.... what we will need to do behind this issue?

Comment: That is a really general question. You have to set several things up...migrations, models etc.